# How can I secure a socket.io connection to send a password to the server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, encryption, socket.io, jwt

I have a frontend running react and I have to authenticate the user with jwt tokens generated on the backend. The question is wether it is save enough to send the plain-text pass over the socket or if I have to encrypt it in a certain way.

Comment: Usually https or wss are good answers

Answer (score 0):

It is totally not safe to send it in plain text unless you use `wss` (WebSocket Secure) which can be done easily by a reverse proxy like, Nginx. Other wise any body on the way can see the username and password, just try `tcpdump` to see the communication data.